# Android - Declaring Full Screen and AppCompatActivity conflict

Tags: android, android-appcompat

When I declare in manifest that my app should be full screen, I do it like this

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

But everytime when i do this it causes an error with extending AppCompatActivity class in my main activity or other classes.So I have to use Activity class to slove this situation but then i have to have less nice graphics. Is there any other way in order to define my app fullscreen which doesn't conflict AppCompatActivity class or is there any solution to solve this current situation mentioned above. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

in manifest

```
<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
```

Answer (score 0):

set the theme in `styles.xml` file as below

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and add this style in `AndroidManifest.xml` file as

```
<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:supportsRtl="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that in manifest and add these lines in activity

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```